# how to store random number in already existing list

Tags: python

Lets say I create a list - Names = John, Alex. I want to store 3 random numbers for each name and find the mean of those 3 numbers for each of them.

Comment: Could you post your code of what you've tried? Otherwise it's hard to guide you.

Comment: Storing those random numbers *in* your list of names seems like a bad idea. Why do you want to do that? It seems more reasonable to create a list of tuples of random numbers, or a dict with tuples of random numbers as values (and probably a better identifier than names as keys, since people can have duplicate names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we're getting three random values for each name and finding the means (in the same order), in a list-based approach.

```py
import random 

names = ["John", "Alex"]

# for each name, create a new list of three random numbers
rand = [[random.random() for _ in range(3)]  for _ in names ]

# find the average of each 'inner list'
means = [sum(x)/len(x) for x in rand]

print(means)
```

Output is, for example:

```
[0.5319106811585387, 0.586153050082146]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create random numbers using by

```
import random

inp_lst = ['John','Alex','Mathew']
n = len(inp_lst)

# using list comprehension + randrange() 
# to generate random number list
rand_lst = [random.randrange(1, 500, 1) for i in range(n)]

mean_lst = sum(rand_lst)/n

res = []

for name,rand in zip(inp_lst,rand_lst):
    res += [[name,rand,mean_lst]]

print(res)

>>> [['John', 445, 429.0], ['Alex', 410, 429.0], ['Mathew', 432, 429.0]]
```